# Find parameters of Generalized Inverse Gaussian Distribution

Tags: distributions, density-function

I have a vector of numbers and I am trying to fit the data by [Generalized Inverse Gaussian Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution). My goal is to estimate the parameters $ a,b,p $ which appears in the pdf function. As in the above wiki page, we know that the pdf function, called $f$, satisfies the following equation:
$$ f(x)(x(ax-2p+2) - b)+2x^2f'(x)=0 $$
My questions are:

1. Can I use this equation to estimate the parameters $a,b,p$?
2. Does there exist other ways to approximate the parameters more accurately?

Comment: 2. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse_Gaussian_distribution) produces some moments, from which you can numerically derive estimates for $a$, $b$, and $p$.

Comment: 2bis. And you can also use a Bayesian approach to estimate the parameters possibly via MCMC algorithms since the pdf is in closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate out the differential equation
$$\int_0^\infty \{f(x)[x(ax-2p+2) - b]+2x^2f'(x)\}\text{d}x=0$$
you get a moment equation
$$\begin{align*}&\int_0^\infty [x(ax-2p+2) - b]f(x)\text{d}x+\int_0^\infty 2x^2f'(x)\}\text{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty [x(ax-2p+2) - b]f(x)\text{d}x-4\int_0^\infty xf(x)\}\text{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty [x(ax-2p+2-4) - b]f(x)\text{d}
=0\end{align*}$$
which can be used in a system of moment equations, but you need two further equations.